# Python3 Itertools Ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, password

```
import itertools
import time

symbols = ['D','E','F','G','2','4','_']
password = 'DGEF_42F4'
lenght = 9

startTime = time.time()
counter = 0
for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(symbols, lenght):
    activeCombination = ''.join(i)
    counter += 1
    if password == activeCombination:
        print(f' Time elapsed - {time.time() - startTime}\n Number of combinations - {counter}\n Password - {activeCombination} ')
```

Этот код должен подбирать пароль, который указан в поле password. Но при запуске ничего не выводится и все завершается, без ошибок. Ничего не выводится(абсолютно). Ошибок нет, но и результата нет. Тестировал этот код на Termux, ибо не имел доступ к ПК. Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: очевидно, что условие в if не выполняется

Comment: @ClarkDevlin оно выполняется только если значения равны. Но в случае моем не выполняется сам цикл for. Программа запускается, и пусть она ничего не печатает, если if не выполняется, но сразу завершать свою работу она не должна. А сейчас она запускается, работает где-то 0.2 секунды и закрывается. Цикл почему-то не срабатывает, ведь раньше он работал, оно также ничего не выводило, если не было совпадений, но работало долго и не закрывалось..

Comment: цикл выполняется. Поставьте в цикле print(counter) и сами увидите. Не выполняется условие.

Comment: Как цикл может выполняться, если код завершается через 0.2 секунды после его запуска? Я запустил этот же код у меня на ПК, он работает уже около получаса, и не закрывается, не перестает работать. Вы когда-нибудь писали ботов для ВК/Телеграма? Там ведь тоже не обязательно ничего в консоль выводить, но ведь они тоже работают while True(то есть, в цикле). Видимо, беда была с термуксом, спасибо

Comment: `Как цикл может выполняться` - вот так и может. Если добавить `print(activeCombination)`, то выводит все комбинации в терминал (т.е. очевидно, что цикл работает). Можно даже перенаправить вывод в файл через `python3 имя_файла.py > result.txt`, и в выводе не будет строки DGEF_42F4. Поэтому if и не срабатывает ни разу.

Comment: Послушайте внимательно. Да, if постоянно сравнивает пароль и новое значение, и ничего(кроме случая совпадения) не выводит. Но if находится в цикле for(), который ДАЖЕ ПРИ НЕ СРАБАТЫВАНИИ if - должен работать. Он ничего не выводит, цикл for перебирает пароли, не выводя их в консоль, вот и все, я имею ввиду то, что не с if была проблема, а с самим циклом. То есть, если я запущу этот скрипт на ПК - он будет работать, хоть ничего и печатать не будет(пока подобранная комбинация не совпадет). Но если я запущу этот же в термуксе, то он попросту завершится, даже не начав подбор. Понимаете?

Comment: Он завершается не потому что if не работает. Ведь подбор комбинации идёт минутами, часами. А код, который был выше(и запускался в термуксе) - вообще не начинал подбор. То есть, он запускался, и МОМЕНТАЛЬНО после запуска закрывался, ничего не делая. А цикл ведь там стоит, и работать он должен даже ничего не печатая. Ну вот если я запущу код while True: time.sleep(30)? Разве он не будет работать? Вот тут также, ничего не печатает, но все работать должно

Comment: В смысле, минутами, часами? Цикл выполняется моментально. На ваших входных данных combinations_with_replacement дает всего 5005 комбинаций, откуда часы?

Comment: combinations_with_replacement не переставляет буквы, он дублирует каждый символ подряд в различных вариантах (0 раз, 1 раз, 2 раза, и т.д.), но не меняет порядок букв. У вас порядок букв в symbols не совпадает с порядком букв в пароле, поэтому нужная комбинация никогда не сгенерируется.

Comment: Мне уже объяснили, я понял, спасибо. И все же сам цикл работать должен был, не смотря на то, что использовал я не то, что надо было использовать. Ещё раз спасибо

Comment: `И все же сам цикл работать должен был` - так он работает. Вы пробовали print внутрь цикла вне условия добавлять? https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6m5Y.png

Answer (score 1):

используйте `itertools.product`

```
for i in itertools.product(symbols, repeat=lenght):
    activeCombination = ''.join(i)
    counter += 1
    if password == activeCombination:
        print(f' Time elapsed - {time.time() - startTime}\n Number of combinations - {counter}\n Password - {activeCombination} ')
```

Comment: я использовал itertools.product, он тоже неплох, но насколько я заметил, Itertools.combinations_with_replacement тоже работает неплохо. Или есть какая-то разница в скорости выполнения?

Comment: @AveMortuus `itertools.product` создаёт все возможные комбинации, `combinations_with_replacement` все возможные перестановки

Comment: понял, спасибо, я думал принципиальной разницы нет..

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю алгоритма `combinations_with_replacement`, но если вы на вход подадите больше символов, то у вас все получится:

```
import itertools


symbols = 'DEFG24_' * 5                               # <<<=======
lenght = 9
password = 'DGEF_42F4'

for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(symbols, lenght):
    activeCombination = ''.join(i)
    if password == activeCombination:
        print(f'Password - {activeCombination}')
        break
```

Comment: combinations_with_replacement работает также, как и обычный combinations, но с одним различием. Можете почитать тут - https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-itertools.html